# Replace the captured image with default image in android

Tags: android, android-volley

when I am trying to upload the default image with captured image,it is not displaying.If I login again then that captured image will display.Why the default image is not changing? In case if the image already exists in the server, it works fine for me.
this is my code.I am using `com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView`

```
 String url = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
        imageLoader = MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(StudentDetails.this).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(url, imageLoader.getImageListener(resultIv,R.drawable.new_back, R.drawable.new_back));
        resultIv.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: When I try to replace the captured image,default image only displaying.But it is uploading in server and when I go back and if I login again I can able to see the captured image.I want to replace captured image when I get a message like "Image uploaded".I am getting correct output if there is an image already exists without any problem.If the image doesn't exist in server,am getting this problem

Comment: Then what you want to see?

Comment: I want to replace the default image after capturing.

Comment: Can anyone tell,how to resolve this problem?